# How do I enter a tuple through raw_input

Tags: tuples, raw-input

I prompt the user to enter a tuple but raw_input converts it to a string. How do I convert it back to a tuple as this is very annoying?

```
    from sympy import *
    plot(y , tuple)
```

The tuple is prompted by the user through raw_input

Comment: Would you like to share what you did ?

Comment: I prompt the user for a range to use to compute the partial sum of a Fourier Series using Sympy,

Comment: Do you want an integer tuple?

Comment: http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html

Comment: Yes...that's perfect!